# Discord py Global Mute command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, command, bots

So, I am trying to create a global mute / unmute command which would be used to mute a specific user in multiple servers. This command is being made only for a community that owns multiple servers so it would be useful to mute someone across all servers where the bot is running.

I based this mute command on a global ban command which is able to ban a user from multiple servers where the bot is running.

The first command "gban" in the below code runs beautifully, whenever I ban a user in one server, it bans them from any other servers the bot is running in. I am trying to see how I can use this same setup to create a global mute command. the command "gmute" is what I have created so far. It works, but it only mutes the user in the server the command is ran in and DOES NOT mute the user in all the servers that the bot is running in. I am trying to make it to where "gmute" is a global command and applies to all servers that the bot is running in.

````
# global ban command

async def gban(ctx, user: discord.User):
  for guild in client.guilds:
    await guild.ban(user)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Global Ban:**", description=f"{user} Has been globally banned from all servers!:no_pedestrians:",colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)


# Global Mute Command

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def gmute(ctx, user: discord.User):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Coventry")

    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Coventry")

        for guild in client.guilds:
            await guild.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Global Mute:**", description=f"**{user} has been globablly muted frm all servers! :zipper_mouth:**", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await user.add_roles(mutedRole)
    await user.send(f"**you have been globally muted!**") ```
````

Comment: I'd like to make it clear for some people that I don't get an error with the gmute command. I am just unsure about how to get the command to execute globally (in all servers that the bot is running in). This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to `add_roles` *inside* the loop.
Your indentation is wrong. the `if not mutedRole:` part should be inside the loop too.
You are creating a new mute role in `ctx.guild` (the guild that the command was done in) and not in `guild` (the guild you got from the loop)
Also, if you create a new mute role, you'd be setting it's permissions only in the guild the role is in, not in all the servers. Instead of doing 2 api calls (`create_role` and `set_permissions`), you can just use the `permissions` keyword argument in `create_role`. So instead of

```py
mutedRole = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Coventry")

for guild in client.guilds:
    await guild.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
```

You'd do

```py
mutedRole = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Coventry", permissions=discord.Permissions(speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False))
```

Your final code will be

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def gmute(ctx, user: discord.User):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Coventry")

        if not mutedRole:
            mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Coventry", permissions=discord.Permissions(speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False))

        member = guild.get_member(user.id)
        await member.add_roles(mutedRole)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Global Mute:**", description=f"**{user} has been globablly muted frm all servers! :zipper_mouth:**", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await user.send(f"**you have been globally muted!**")
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! I have implemented this version of the command keep getting an error arising, I had the same one while working on the code the other night. Any idea what maybe causing this?

`File "C:\Users\Nitro\Desktop\Python\Python Scripts\GlobalBot\GlobalBot.py", line 45, in gmute
    await user.add_roles(mutedRole)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

Comment: that's probably happening because you are trying to add a role from a guild to a member from another guild. Did you change the typehint of `user` from `discord.User` to `discord.Member`? That could be causing the error as `user` would be from the guild that the command was done in. I realized a fault in my answer, I forgot that you need a `discord.Member` object to use add_roles and I have edited it now.

Comment: Thank you for the response SYCK, I have updated the code and unfortunately am getting a new error. I have been messing around with it to see if I could get fix it by chance. 

``` File "C:\Users\Nitro\Desktop\Python\Python Scripts\GlobalBot\GlobalBot.py", line 79, in mute
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole)

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles' ```

Comment: I figured out the issue, I had intents turned on in my code. But did not have intents turned on for the bot in discord developer. I can't believe that. Thank you for your help and time. The code fix you provided is now working!